# How to find out the delayed jobs in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Some of my DAG are waiting to get scheduled, and some are waiting in the queue. I suspect there are reasons for this delay but not sure how I can start to debug this problem. Majority of the pipelines are running Spark jobs.

Can someone help to give me some directions in terms of where to look at to 1) anaylse which DAGs were delayed (did not start at the scheduled time) 2) where are the places I should look at to find out if the resources are enough. I'm quite new to scheduling in Airflow. Many thanks. Please let me know if I can describe the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for code that takes advantage of Airflows' wider capabilities.

There are three modules within `airflow.models` which can be harnessed.

1. To programmatically retrieve all DAGs which your Airflow is away of, we import [DagBag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagbag/index.html). From the docs "*A dagbag is a collection of dags, parsed out of a folder tree and has high*"
2. We utilise [DagModel and the method get_current](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html?highlight=utils#airflow.models.dag.DagModel.get_current), to initialise each dag_id present in our bag
3. We check if any DAG is active using the DagModel property [is_paused](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html?highlight=utils#airflow.models.dag.DagModel.is_paused)
4. We retrieve the latest DAG run using the [DagRun.find](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun.find)
5. Sort the individual dag runs by latest to earliest
6. Here you could just subset [0] to get 1, however, for your debugging purposes I just loop through them all
7. [DagRun](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun) returns a lot of information for us to use. In my loop I have output `print(i, run.state, run.execution_date, run.start_date)`. So you can see what is going on under the hood.

> id
> state
> dag_id
> queued_at
> execution_date
> start_date
> end_date
> run_id
> data_interval_start
> data_interval_end
> last_scheduling_decision

8. I have commented out an if check for any queued Dags for you to uncomment. Additionally you can do some arithmetic on dates if you desire, to add further conditional functionality.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import DagBag, DagModel, DagRun
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


# make a function that returns if a DAG is set to active or paused

def check_dag_active():
    bag = DagBag()
    for dag_id in bag.dags:
        in_bag = DagModel.get_current(dag_id)
        if not in_bag.is_paused:
            latest = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
            latest.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=True)
            for i, run in enumerate(latest):
                print(i, run.state, run.execution_date, run.start_date)
                # if run.state == 'queued':
                #     return [run.dag_id, run.execution_date, run.start_date]

with DAG(
  'stack_overflow_ans_3',
  tags = ['SO'],
  start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
  schedule_interval = None,
  catchup = False,
  is_paused_upon_creation = False
) as dag:

  t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'task_that_will_fail',
    python_callable = check_dag_active
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! Does `is_paused` mean the ones that are not running?  They paused because they are not scheduled? or could it be possible for some other reason?

Comment: @user4046073 is_paused based on my experience are those that have been deactivated/paused in the web UI via the toggle or CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Airflow and your setup, you should be able to query the Airflow DB directly to get this information.

If you're using Airflow 1.x, there should be an "Ad Hoc Query" executor in the Data Profiling tab in the UI. This was disabled in 2.x though, so if you're running 2.x you'll need to connect directly to your Airflow DB using `psql` or something similar (this differs from Google to AWS to Docker).

Once you're in, check out [this link](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-queries/) for some queries on DAG runtime.

Comment: thanks yes I've had a look at the metadata, however I still struggling of getting the right columns to use, for example to find out the delayed dag, I tried to calculate (queued_dttm- execution_date) to see how long after the scheduled execution time it was queued. But whenever the dag was trigger manually, the queued_dttm would be overwritten..

Comment: @user4046073 Check the `dag_run` table instead of the `dag` table, there's a new record for every time the DAG is executed. Filter by the `run_type` column, that'll tell you if it's SCHEDULED or MANUAL, then you can compare the `queued_at` and `start_date` columns I believe.

Again, depends on your Airflow version though. If the above doesn't apply, try the `task_instance` table.

Comment: thanks. when a run was cleared, `run_type` would also show as SCHEDULED, right?

Comment: @user4046073 If that instance that you cleared was a scheduled run, then it will. If you executed the DAG manually and then cleared it, it'll show as MANUAL.